# How can I create simple poker hand algorithms?

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

So I have been creating this simple poker game in java.  I have Created a deck of cards (The cards are objects that consist of a string and integer) and array lists to represent your hand and the dealers hand.  Once I have cards in the yourHand array, how can I create a way to check for different suits? I want to keep it simple like having it only check for pairs and 3 of a kind.  How can I approach this? The way I think it may be done, is to create a loop that will check each element in the array, and see if any of those elements are equal to another. But that seems easier said then done as I really don't understand how I would do that. And then the idea comes up, would it be an issue to do it that way since the card objects are of type String AND integer? I'm new to programming and will appreciate any help. Thanks! (also, let me know if you guys would like to see my code that sets up the card objects, which I have in a different class)

public class pokerMain implements StackInterFace {

```
public static void main (String [] args){
    ArrayList<String> suits = new ArrayList<String>();//array list for the card suits
    ArrayList<Integer> val = new ArrayList<Integer>();//array list for card values
    ArrayList<CARDS> newCards = new ArrayList<CARDS>();//array list for cards with assigned val/suits
    ArrayList<CARDS> yourHand = new ArrayList<CARDS>();//array list for your hand
    ArrayList<CARDS> dealerHand = new ArrayList<CARDS>();//array list for the dealer's hand
    Stack<CARDS> deck = new Stack();//Stack to represent deck
    suits.add("Clubs");//These are the suits, added to the suits ArrayList
    suits.add("Hearts");
    suits.add("Diamonds");
    suits.add("Spades");

    System.out.println("suits contains: " + suits );//Testing for suit

    for(int i = 1; i <= 13; i ++){//loop that adds all 13 values to to the val ArrayList
        val.add(i);
    }

    System.out.println("val contains " + val);//Testing for val


    for(Integer i : val) {//second attempt of adding objects to newCards
        for(String s : suits) {
            newCards.add(new CARDS(s, i));
        }
    }

    System.out.println("the full deck contains: ");

    System.out.println(newCards.toString());//prints newCards arrayList

    Collections.shuffle(newCards);//shuffles array newCards

    System.out.println("When shuffled this is what is in the deck");
    System.out.println(newCards.toString());//prints shuffled array

    deck.addAll(newCards);//adds newCards into the decks stack




    System.out.println("Test print stack");
    System.out.println(deck.toString());//prints stack as test

    System.out.println("You pulled a " + deck.pop());//test pulling card from deck

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i ++){//loop to draw cards and put into hand
        yourHand.add(deck.pop());
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i ++){//loop to draw cards and put into hand
        dealerHand.add(deck.pop());
    }

    System.out.println("Please draw your cards");
    System.out.println("Your hand contains:");
    System.out.println(yourHand.toString());

    for(int i = 0; i < yourHand.size(); i ++){//loop to check for pairs

    }
}





@Override
public Object pop() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public Object peek() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public void clear() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



@Override
public void push(ArrayList newCards) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}



@Override
public void addAll(ArrayList newCards) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

One simple way is to sort the cards by face value.  That makes it easy to find N of the same values in a row.

I don't write java, so this is probably full of syntax errorrs,  but do something like:

```
class CardFaceComparartor implements Comparator<CARD>
    public int compare(CARD a, CARD b) {
       return a.getFaceval() - b.getFaceaval;
    }
 }

...

Collections.sort(yourHand, CardFaceComparator);
int numSame=1;
int sets[4] = {0,0,0,0}  //counts singles, pairs, ...
bool maybeFlush=True;
for (i=0; i<yourHand.size()-; i++) {
   if (yourHand[i].getFaceval()==   yourHand[i-1].getFaceval())
       numSame+=1;
   else {
      sets[numSame]+=1;
      numSame = 1;
  }
  maybeFlush = maybeFlush & (yourHand[i].getSuit() == yourHand[i-1.getSuit());

}
// now you have all the info to find best hand.
```

Comment: Would I have to use setters and getters to use the face value?

Comment: Well, yes if the fields are private (they should be). He/She means sort YOUR hand (or dealers / other players) and checking for straights becomes easier, as well as pairs, full house, etc. Flushes on the other hand don't get any easier but all you have to do is check if all cards are of the same suit, and you can stop checking when you see the first dis-simliar card suit from the first card you check

Comment: dang, I left an answer with a similar response... :P

Comment: well then, have a +1.

Answer (score 1):

Consider this example of using a Comparator and the Collections utils:

```
public static final Comparator comparator = new Comparator<Card>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Card cardOne, Card cardTwo) {
            return cardOne.getFaceVal().compareTo(cardTwo.getFaceVal());
        }
    };

/* Later on we can then use the comparator object to sort! */   
Collections.sort(cards, comparator);
```

Make the fields of your Card object have type String for Suit, and of type Integer for value. Then the above code can be applied to sort a particular ArrayList that contains Card objects such as your hand, or the dealers hand, etc.. What you gain from this is checking for straights, pairs, etc can be optimized and easier since everything is in ascending order.

Here is an example of a hand before sort:

5, 4, Q, 5, 2

Without the sort, you can see checking for a straight is very hard to while then also needing to find pairs... The algorithm would be to see you have a 5, and check for a straight like [5,6,7,8,9] by looking through the rest of the cards, and that is difficult to also keep track of pairs. The logic would get very messy in code, and hard to test or have someone else read. By sorting it we would get

2, 3, 4, 5, 5

We can, in one scan, see there is no straight as well as finding pairs. We know to expect the subsequent card to be just one value greater than the last card, and if it's not no straight can exist. If it's the same value it's a pair! More logic is involved at well for finding a three of a kind, 4 of a kind, etc.. but I'll leave that exercise up to you!

There will be edge cases for an Ace though, as it in some games can be used in sequence with 2, 3, 4, 5 to be a straight.. You didn't say what poke game you were making. Also ensure to consider J-A to be 11-14 respectively.